# Slow performance of Neo4j Cyhper IN operator vs equivalent equality operator

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Consider the following query:

```
MATCH (task:Task)--(assignment:Assignment)
WHERE task.Uid IN ['7d261f24-781b-4bf7-a1a5-ab8987d51164']
RETURN assignment
```

In our database, we have approximately 750,000 tasks and 1100 assignments.

The performance of this query runs in the 12-13 second range with an index on `Task.Uid`.

However, this query runs in the 10-20ms range:

```
MATCH (task:Task)--(assignment:Assignment)
WHERE task.Uid = '7d261f24-781b-4bf7-a1a5-ab8987d51164'
RETURN assignment
```

I would have expected these two queries to run at the same speed, but it seems that the query engine is treating them very differently even though in this case, where the collection length is 1, the query is the same.

I have tried variations like switching the `IN` to use `OR`, but the performance is the same (12-13s) in a case like this:

```
MATCH (task:Task)--(assignment:Assignment)
WHERE task.Uid = '7d261f24-781b-4bf7-a1a5-ab8987d51164' 
    OR task.Uid = '971b786e-01ae-4726-a0f6-d0bc494df167'
RETURN assignment
```

However, this query performs the same (10-20ms) as the equality query:

```
MATCH (task1:Task)--(assignment1:Assignment),
    (task2:Task)--(assignment2:Assignment)
WHERE task1.Uid = '7d261f24-781b-4bf7-a1a5-ab8987d51164' 
    AND task2.Uid = '971b786e-01ae-4726-a0f6-d0bc494df167'
RETURN assignment1, assignment2
```

The question is whether there is any way to more elegantly write the second query using Cypher?

I guess I'm also confused why the `IN` and `OR` aren't translated into index lookups in this case whereas the equality operator is.

Comment: Wondering: Is "Uid" an indexed property?

Comment: Yes, `Uid` is an indexed property as stated in the second sentence :D

Comment: Sorry. My bad for having missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is a missing implementation right now. :(

You can use something like your last approach, or perhaps better UNION between multiple queries of type (2)

```
MATCH (task:Task)--(assignment:Assignment)
WHERE task.Uid = '7d261f24-781b-4bf7-a1a5-ab8987d51164' 
RETURN assignment
UNION
MATCH (task:Task)--(assignment:Assignment)
WHERE task.Uid = '971b786e-01ae-4726-a0f6-d0bc494df167'
RETURN assignment
```

Comment: Union is where I was already experimenting, but I was hoping for something a bit more intelligent.  Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

This has been addressed in 2.1.2 release version:

http://neo4j.com/blog/neo4j-2-1-2/?_ga=1.172697573.754304541.1400274053

> Cypher uses indexes for resolving WHERE clauses which use the IN operator